# update listview after a change in another view

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView, when you click on the plus it leads to a second activity where you can add data and click OK. When you click OK, the data of the previous activity in the list should be updated.
i tried invalidateViews() and notifyDataSetChanged() in all kinds of places but it did not work.

this is the list activity:

```
public class EditActivity extends ListActivity {

EditAdapter adapter;
String itemName;
String sectionTopic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    sectionTopic = extra.getString("topic");

    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    getListView().addHeaderView(header);
    adapter= new EditAdapter(getApplicationContext(),sectionTopic);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

the adaptor:

```
public class EditAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<EditSection> arrayList= new ArrayList<EditSection>();
private Context mContext;
String topicNameS;


public EditAdapter(Context mContext, String topicName) {
    super();
    this.mContext = mContext;
    topicNameS = topicName;
    arrayList = new ArrayList<EditSection>();

    DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(mContext);

    List<SectionItems> items = dataModel.getSectionsForTopic(topicName);


    for (SectionItems item: items){
        double sectionBudget = dataModel.getBudgetForSection(item);
        double sectionExpense = dataModel.getSumOfExpensesForSection(item);

        arrayList.add(new EditSection(item.getSectionItemsPic(),item.getSectionItemsName(), sectionBudget, sectionExpense));
        }   
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View vowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_edit, parent, false);

    if (position%2==1){
        vowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(170, 218, 203));
    }
    else{
        vowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(147, 213, 212));
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView budget = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.budget);
    TextView expense = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.expense);
    ImageView pic = (ImageView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.pic);
    View itemV = vowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    TextView button = (TextView) vowView.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);            return vowView;
}
}
```

and the OK button in the second activity, where the data changes:

```
public void conformation (View v){
DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(getBaseContext());

Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
String itemId = extra.getString("title");
SectionItems item = DataModel.getItemForId(itemId);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(yy, mm, dd);
Date dateNew= calendar.getTime();

if (isUpdate){
    dataModel.updateExpense(dateNew, rowId, item, num, Double.parseDouble(sectionAmount));

} else if (num!=0 ){
    dataModel.addExpense(dateNew, item, num);
}
finish();
```

}

Comment: I assume dataModel is a Database, does it insert data correctly?

Comment: Where are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Do you update the `arrayList` that is created in your `EditAdapter` constructor?

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah- the insert is correctly. I wanted to update but i didnt know where.there is no update in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest suggestion (not elegant) to this would be doing

```
adapter= new EditAdapter(getApplicationContext(),sectionTopic);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

in the onResume() function of EditActivity.

The proper way would be calling startActivityForResult so your second activity could pass back what is added

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is there a way to update only the change and not build a new adapter? because loading takes a long time..

Comment: yes, that would be using startActivityForResult, where your second activity would define its added item as result.